# OpenCV: Reducing "fuzzy maxima" into single points

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have used:

```
result = cv2.matchTemplate(frame, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
```

to generate this output:
[image]
I need a list of (x, y) tuples at each of the local maxima (bright spots) in the result.  Simply finding all points above a threshold doesn't work, since there are many such points around each maximum.

I can guarantee the minimum distance between any two maxima, which ought to help speed things up.

Is there an efficient technique for doing this?

(P.S.: this is cross-posted from https://forum.opencv.org/t/locating-local-maximums/1534)

### update

Based on an [excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66193405/558639) by [Michael Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4318157/michael-lee), I've added skeletonizing to the thresholded image.  It's close, but the skeletonizing still has many "worms" rather than single points.  My processing flow is as follows:

```
# read the image
im = cv.imread("image.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# apply thresholding
ret, im2 = cv.threshold(im, args.threshold, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
# dilate the thresholded image to eliminate "pinholes"
im3 = cv.dilate(im2, None, iterations=2)
# skeletonize the result
im4 = cv.ximgproc.thinning(im3, None, cv.ximgproc.THINNING_ZHANGSUEN)
# print the number of points found
x, y = np.nonzero(im5)
print(x.shape)
# => 1208
```

This is a step in the right direction, but there should be more like 220 points, not 1208.

Here are the intermediate results.  As you can see in the last picture (skeletonized), there are still lots of little "worms" rather than single point.  Is there a better approach?

Thresholded:
[image]

Dilated:
[image]

Skeletonized:
[image]

Comment: if the points above the threshold are connected you can use skeletonization or blob-detection or contour-extraction+center-of-gravity. If the points above threshold are not connected you could try to find clusters of distances between points above the threshold. If you are lucky there is a clear distance threshold under which you  merge points (and again use the center of gravity to find the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2/14**:  Seems like skeletonization only took you part of the way there.  Here's a better solution which I believe should get you the rest of the way.  Here's how you would do it in scikit-image - maybe you can find the analog in OpenCV - seems like `cv2.findContours` would be a good start.

```
# mask is the thresholded image (before or after dilation should work, no skeletonization.

from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
labeled_image = label(mask)
output_points = [region.centroid for region in regionprops(labeled_image)]
```

Explanation:  Label will convert your binary image into a labeled image, where each mask has a different integer value.  Then, regionprops uses these labels in order to separate each mask, from which we can use the centroid property to compute the middle point from each - this is guaranteed to be a single point.

---

> Simply finding all points above a threshold doesn't work, since there
> are many such points around each maximum.

Actually, this does work - as long as you apply one more processing step.  After thresholding, then we want to skeletonize.  Scikit-image has a good function to achieve that [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html), which should give you a binary mask with single points.

Afterwards, you're probably going to want to run something like:

```
indices = zip(*np.where(skeleton))
```

to get your final points!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in this direction.  FWIW, newer versions of cv2 include a skeletonizing function: https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html#ga37002c6ca80c978edb6ead5d6b39740c -- I'll give it a try.

Comment: @fearless_fool updated my answer with a better solution that should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Michael Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66193405/558639), here's the solution that worked for me (using all openCV rather than skimage):

```
# read in color image and create a grayscale copy
im = cv.imread("image.png")
img = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply thresholding
ret, im2 = cv.threshold(img, args.threshold, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
# dilate the thresholded peaks to eliminate "pinholes"
im3 = cv.dilate(im2, None, iterations=2)

contours, hier = cv.findContours(im3, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print('found', len(contours), 'contours')
# draw a bounding box around each contour
for contour in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(contour)
    cv.rectangle(im, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)

cv.imshow('Contours', im)
cv.waitKey()
```

which results in just what we're looking for:

[image]